# Reversibility and irreversibility of logic gates (quantum vs classical)

Tags: quantum-gate, classical-computing

I have been told that one of the great *keys* that unlock quantum computing's potential is the reversibility of quantum logic gates as for classical gates there's some loss of information, but I cannot grasp this concept. Mathematically I see why the quantum logic gate is reversible, it is a mere unitary operator but on the classical one I don't see where the information is lost, could someone clarify it?

Comment: **Related**: [If quantum gates are reversible how can they possibly perform irreversible classical AND and OR operations?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/131/if-quantum-gates-are-reversible-how-can-they-possibly-perform-irreversible-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mathematically I see why the quantum logic gate is reversible, it is a
>   mere unitary operator but on the classical one I don't see where the
>   information is lost, could someone clarify it?

For illustration, let's take the classical [`XOR` gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate).

[image]

Say you know that the output or end result of a certain `XOR` operation is `1`. Now what could have been the possible values for `A` and `B`? Either `A = 0` & `B = 1` or `A=1` & `B = 0`. That is, you cannot *unambiguously* reconstruct its two inputs from its single output i.e. the information about the initial state of `A` and `B` is lost after the XOR logic operation. This is exactly what they mean when they mean by "irreversibility of classical logic gates".

Interestingly, the reversible *quantum* version of the `XOR` gate is the [`CNOT` gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controlled_NOT_gate).

However, there are exceptions like the classical [`NOT` gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverter_(logic_gate)).

[image]

For the `NOT` gate, if you're given that the output state `1`, then you can unambiguously say the initial state of `A` was `0`. Similarly, if you're given `NOT A` is `0`, you can unambiguously say that `A` was `1`. No information is lost here during the logic operation.

It's possible to perform all classical logic operations using only reversible gates. But in those cases, often it becomes necessary to use [ancilla bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancilla_bit). For instance, the reversible [Toffoli gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate) gate can implement all classical logic functions. The Toffoli gate has a quantum version too. Basically, all reversible classical logic operations can be directly mapped to quantum gate operations, which are unitary and reversible. In case you're wondering *why* quantum gates are unitary, read [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/2040).

> I have been told that one of the great keys that unlock quantum
>   computing's potential is the reversibility of quantum logic gates as
>   for classical gates there's some loss of information, but I cannot
>   grasp this concept.

That's true. Read up the Wikipedia articles on [reversible computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing) and [Landauer's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle). Note that there's two kinds of reversibilities: [logical reversibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing#Logical_reversibility) and [physical reversibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing#Physical_reversibility). A [universal Turing machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Turing_machine) can be made both physically and logically reversible. Logical and physical reversibility together would enable running [efficient algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algorithm) and energy-efficient computation in quantum computers.

Comment: It's a good question. Writing this answer prompted me to ask [How exactly is logical reversibility useful?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5278)