# Implementing "Classical AND Gate" and "Classical OR Gate" with a quantum circuit

Tags: quantum-gate, classical-computing, unitarity

## Quantum cNOT Gate (Classical XOR Gate)

A "Controlled NOT (cNOT) Gate" flips the 2nd qubit if the 1st qubit is $\left|1\right>$, and returns the 2nd qubit as-is if the 1st qubit is $\left|0\right>$. The 1st qubit is simply not changed.

The net effect of this gate is a classical XOR gate:

- It keeps the 1st qubit unchanged
- It outputs "the 1st qubit XOR the 2nd qubit" as the result of the 2nd qubit

In table form, the function looks like:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}1 & \color{red}{1}\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}1 & \color{red}{0}\end{array} \\
 \hline  
\end{array}
$$

Therefore, an input:

$$\alpha\left|00\right>+\beta\left|01\right>+\gamma\left|10\right>+\delta\left|11\right>$$

is mapped to:

$$\alpha\left|00\right>+\beta\left|01\right>+\gamma\left|1\color{red}{1}\right>+\delta\left|1\color{red}{0}\right>$$

Or, in other words:

$$\alpha\left|00\right>+\beta\left|01\right>+\color{red}{\delta}\left|10\right>+\color{red}{\gamma}\left|11\right>$$

In matrix form, we need to find the all the $a_{ij}$'s that satisfy the following:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
    a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha \\
    \beta \\
    \gamma \\
    \delta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha \\
    \beta \\
    \color{red}{\delta} \\
    \color{red}{\gamma} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

It is trivial to find the solution:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
    0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha \\
    \beta \\
    \gamma \\
    \delta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha \\
    \beta \\
    \color{red}{\delta} \\
    \color{red}{\gamma} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

---

## Quantum AND Gate?

Similarly, if there exists a gate that mimics the classical AND gate, it should have the following net effect:

- It keeps the 1st qubit unchanged
- It outputs "the 1st qubit AND the 2nd qubit" as the result of the 2nd qubit

In table form, the function looks like:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}0 & \color{red}{0}\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline  
\end{array}
$$

Therefore, an input:

$$\alpha\left|00\right>+\beta\left|01\right>+\gamma\left|10\right>+\delta\left|11\right>$$

should be mapped to:

$$\alpha\left|00\right>+\beta\left|0\color{red}{0}\right>+\gamma\left|10\right>+\delta\left|11\right>$$

Or, in other words:

$$\color{red}{(\alpha+\beta)}\left|00\right>+\color{red}{0}\left|01\right>+\gamma\left|10\right>+\delta\left|11\right>$$

In matrix form, we need to find the all the $a_{ij}$'s that satisfy the following:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
    a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha \\
    \beta \\
    \gamma \\
    \delta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \color{red}{\alpha+\beta} \\
    \color{red}{0} \\
    \gamma \\
    \delta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

It is trivial to find the solution:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & \color{red}{0} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha \\
    \beta \\
    \gamma \\
    \delta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \color{red}{\alpha+\beta} \\
    \color{red}{0} \\
    \gamma \\
    \delta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

---

## Quantum OR Gate?

Similarly, if there exists a gate that mimics the classical OR gate, it should have the following net effect:

- It keeps the 1st qubit unchanged
- It outputs "the 1st qubit OR the 2nd qubit" as the result of the 2nd qubit

In table form, the function looks like:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}1 & \color{red}{1}\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline  
\end{array}
$$

Therefore, an input:

$$\alpha\left|00\right>+\beta\left|01\right>+\gamma\left|10\right>+\delta\left|11\right>$$

should be mapped to:

$$\alpha\left|00\right>+\beta\left|01\right>+\gamma\left|1\color{red}{1}\right>+\delta\left|11\right>$$

Or, in other words:

$$\alpha\left|00\right>+\beta\left|01\right>+\color{red}{0}\left|10\right>+\color{red}{(\gamma+\delta)}\left|11\right>$$

In matrix form, we need to find the all the $a_{ij}$'s that satisfy the following:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
    a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha \\
    \beta \\
    \gamma \\
    \delta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha \\
    \beta \\
    \color{red}{0} \\
    \color{red}{\gamma+\delta} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

It is trivial to find the solution:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    \cdot
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha \\
    \beta \\
    \gamma \\
    \delta \\
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha \\
    \beta \\
    \color{red}{0} \\
    \color{red}{\gamma+\delta} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

---

However, since:

$$
    A
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & \color{red}{0} & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

and

$$
    B
    =
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

are not unitary matrices, as shown by $\det(A) = \det(B) = 0 \ne 1$, they could not be implemented directly as a quantum logic gate.

I have read the answer here:

[If quantum gates are reversible how can they possibly perform irreversible classical AND and OR operations?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/132/6152)

but it is not intuitive enough for me:

- to understand what the final solution is; and
- to visualize how it achieves the same result as the matrix $A$ and $B$ above.

Does anyone have any idea on how to implement "Classical AND" and "Classical OR" with an explanation in matrix form? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use an ancilla qubit and find an 8x8 unitary instead. See the section on "arbitrary boolean functions" [here](https://nosarthur.github.io/quantum%20information%20and%20computation/2018/02/17/boolean-gates.html).

Comment: @Blue Thanks! In fact I have already read Wikipedia before asking the question, and I am reading the link you posted in your previous comment (the same as the recent comment).

Comment: You don't need to do anything fancy to get back `a AND b` I think. Just set it as `0` initially. `0 XOR 0` is `0`, and `0 XOR 1` is `1`. That is, `c XOR (a AND b) = a AND b` if you take `c` as `0`. Basically, set the ancillary qubit to $|0\rangle$ initially, and you'll get required output at the third "wire".

Comment: From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Toffoli_(CCNOT)_gate) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate#Universality_and_Toffoli_gate), I know that Toffoli gate maps the input `{a, b, c}` to `{a, b, c XOR (a AND b)`. To get back `(a AND b)`, we can do a `XOR c` to the result. However, since the output is at the wire c, and qubits could not be copied, how could I do a `XOR c` after that? Let's say if we set $c=\left|0\right>$, can we use another qubit $d=\left|0\right>$ instead of c, and do a `XOR d` to get the same result?

Comment: @Blue : Oh yes... I got it now... Too silly to overlook that `0 XOR x = x` for any `x`. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your *construction by gueswork* in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5834)  is OK but not really elegant. Moreover, it's a convention to start in the state $|0\rangle$; we usually don't initialize a qubit with the state $|1\rangle$. It's better to follow the general construction which I illustrate here.

---

The idea here is to use ancillary qubits and impose unitary evolution on the larger system instead i.e. by treating the two-qubit system as a subsystem. There's a general method for constructing such gates. Essentially, you are trying to construct a quantum gate that'll perform a Boolean mapping like $f: \{0, 1\}^n \longrightarrow \{0, 1\}$. You've noted that for $n=2$ (two qubits), you cannot constructing unitary gates corresponding to some classical operations like the AND and OR as there's a rank deficiency (this happens precisely because those classical operations [are irreversible](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5276)). So we'll try with $n=3$ instead. Let's take the example of the quantum OR gate, which would perform the mapping $$|a \ b \ c\rangle \mapsto |a \ b \ c\oplus(a+b)\rangle$$ where $a,b,c \in \{0,1\}$. By the way, $\oplus$ here stands for XOR and $+$ stands for OR. You do know that $0 \oplus x = x$ for any $x \in \{0,1\}$? Otherwise, check the [XOR table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate). Thus, if we set the additional qubit to $|0\rangle$ initially, it boils down to $$|a \ b \ 0\rangle \mapsto |a \ b \ a+b\rangle.$$

Let's construct the table now.

$$\begin{array}{|c c c|c c c|}
\hline
a & b & c & a & b & c\oplus (a+b) \\ \hline
0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{0}       \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1       \\ \hline
0 & 1 & \color{red}{0} & 0 & 1 & \color{red}{1}       \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0       \\ \hline
1 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & 1 & 0 & \color{red}{1}       \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0       \\ \hline
1 & 1 & \color{red}{0} & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{1}       \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0       \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

We're only only concerned with the cases where $c=0$ i.e. the ones marked in red. Half done now! If we translate this to mapping of the computational basis vectors of the three-qubit system, we get

$$|000\rangle \mapsto |000\rangle \equiv [1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]^T \mapsto \color{blue}{[1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]^T}$$
$$|001\rangle \mapsto |001\rangle \equiv [0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]^T \mapsto \color{brown}{[0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]^T}$$
$$|010\rangle \mapsto |011\rangle \equiv [0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]^T \mapsto \color{teal}{[0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]^T}$$
$$|011\rangle \mapsto |010\rangle \equiv [0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]^T \mapsto \color{violet}{[0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]^T}$$
$$|100\rangle \mapsto |101\rangle \equiv [0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]^T \mapsto \color{green}{[0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0]^T}$$
$$|101\rangle \mapsto |100\rangle \equiv [0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0]^T \mapsto \color{magenta}{[0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0]^T}$$
$$|110\rangle \mapsto |111\rangle \equiv [0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0]^T \mapsto \color{orange}{[0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1]^T}$$
$$|111\rangle \mapsto |110\rangle \equiv [0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1]^T \mapsto \color{purple}{[0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 0 \ 1 \ 0]^T}$$

The columns vectors highlighted in blue will the columns of the required matrix cf. [change of basis transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Transformation_matrix). The matrix is certainly unitary as basis vectors are simply getting mapped to basis vectors, and the mapping is [bijective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection).

$$\color{red}{\text{quantum OR}} = \begin{pmatrix}
{\color{blue} 1} & {\color{brown} 0} & {\color{teal} 0} & {\color{violet} 0} & {\color{green} 0} & {\color{magenta} 0} & {\color{orange} 0} & {\color{purple} 0} \\ 
{\color{blue} 0} & {\color{brown} 1} & {\color{teal} 0} & {\color{violet} 0} & {\color{green} 0} & {\color{magenta} 0} & {\color{orange} 0} & {\color{purple} 0} \\ 
{\color{blue} 0} & {\color{brown} 0} & {\color{teal} 0} & {\color{violet} 1} & {\color{green} 0} & {\color{magenta} 0} & {\color{orange} 0} & {\color{purple} 0} \\
{\color{blue} 0} & {\color{brown} 0} & {\color{teal} 1} & {\color{violet} 0} & {\color{green} 0} & {\color{magenta} 0} & {\color{orange} 0} & {\color{purple} 0} \\
{\color{blue} 0} & {\color{brown} 0} & {\color{teal} 0} & {\color{violet} 0} & {\color{green} 0} & {\color{magenta} 1} & {\color{orange} 0} & {\color{purple} 0} \\
{\color{blue} 0} & {\color{brown} 0} & {\color{teal} 0} & {\color{violet} 0} & {\color{green} 1} & {\color{magenta} 0} & {\color{orange} 0} & {\color{purple} 0} \\
{\color{blue} 0} & {\color{brown} 0} & {\color{teal} 0} & {\color{violet} 0} & {\color{green} 0} & {\color{magenta} 0} & {\color{orange} 0} & {\color{purple} 1} \\
{\color{blue} 0} & {\color{brown} 0} & {\color{teal} 0} & {\color{violet} 0} & {\color{green} 0} & {\color{magenta} 0} & {\color{orange} 1} & {\color{purple} 0} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Calculate the determinant and convince yourself that it's unitary.

**Exercise:**

1. Use the method demonstrated here to construct the quantum gates corresponding to the classical NAND, NOR and XNOR gates.
2. Prove that the mapping defined by $(a,b,c)\mapsto (a, b, c\oplus f(a,b))$ is one-one and onto, where $f$ is any arbitrary [Boolean function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_function) of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand [your answer of your own question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/132/6152) now!

Comment: Thanks. Is there any direct way to find the 3(+1 ancillary)-qubit circuit for the quantum OR gate?

Answer (score 8):

## Simulating Classical "AND/NAND/OR/NOR/XOR/XNOR" Gates

With the help of [this answer from Blue](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5838/6152), constructing a matrix for a classical gate is just a matter of following the steps.

Here is the combined truth table for classical logic gates:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{AND} & \text{NAND} & \text{OR} & \text{NOR} & \text{XOR} & \text{XNOR} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\end{array} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\end{array} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\end{array} & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\end{array} & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \hline
\end{array}
$$

It could be seen that since the output of **AND**, **NAND**, **OR**, and **XOR** do not have equal number of 0's and 1's, they need an [ancilla bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancilla_bit). For **XOR** and **XNOR**, no ancilla bit is needed.

Below is a table for the mappings and matrices.

The light color mappings represent mappings that are "not used", since the ancilla bit is always prepared to be $\left|0\right>$ by convention.

A color tone groups a pair of mapping swap, which is necessary to achieve reversibility and keep the matrix a unitary matrix.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Gate} & \text{Mapping} & \text{Matrix} \\
 \hline
 \text{AND} &
 \begin{array}{}
  \left|000\right> \mapsto \left|000\right> \\
  \color{#999}{\left|001\right> \mapsto \left|001\right>} \\
  \left|010\right> \mapsto \left|010\right> \\
  \color{#999}{\left|011\right> \mapsto \left|011\right>} \\
  \left|100\right> \mapsto \left|100\right> \\
  \color{#999}{\left|101\right> \mapsto \left|101\right>} \\
  \left|110\right> \mapsto \color{#f00}{\left|111\right>} \\
  \color{#999}{\left|111\right> \mapsto \color{#f99}{\left|110\right>}} \\
 \end{array} &
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{#f00}{0} & \color{#f00}{1} \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{#f00}{1} & \color{#f00}{0} \\
 \end{pmatrix} \\
 \hline
 \text{NAND} &
 \begin{array}{}
  \left|000\right> \mapsto \color{#f00}{\left|001\right>} \\
  \color{#999}{\left|001\right> \mapsto \color{#f99}{\left|000\right>}} \\
  \left|010\right> \mapsto \color{#0b5}{\left|011\right>} \\
  \color{#999}{\left|011\right> \mapsto \color{#7b9}{\left|010\right>}} \\
  \left|100\right> \mapsto \color{#07c}{\left|101\right>} \\
  \color{#999}{\left|101\right> \mapsto \color{#7ac}{\left|100\right>}} \\
  \left|110\right> \mapsto \left|110\right> \\
  \color{#999}{\left|111\right> \mapsto \left|111\right>} \\
 \end{array} &
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \color{#f00}{0} & \color{#f00}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \color{#f00}{1} & \color{#f00}{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \color{#0b5}{0} & \color{#0b5}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \color{#0b5}{1} & \color{#0b5}{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{#07c}{0} & \color{#07c}{1} & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{#07c}{1} & \color{#07c}{0} & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{pmatrix} \\
 \hline
 \text{OR} &
 \begin{array}{}
  \left|000\right> \mapsto \left|000\right> \\
  \color{#999}{\left|001\right> \mapsto \left|001\right>} \\
  \left|010\right> \mapsto \color{#f00}{\left|011\right>} \\
  \color{#999}{\left|011\right> \mapsto \color{#f99}{\left|010\right>}} \\
  \left|100\right> \mapsto \color{#0b5}{\left|101\right>} \\
  \color{#999}{\left|101\right> \mapsto \color{#7b9}{\left|100\right>}} \\
  \left|110\right> \mapsto \color{#07c}{\left|111\right>} \\
  \color{#999}{\left|111\right> \mapsto \color{#7ac}{\left|110\right>}} \\
 \end{array} &
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \color{#f00}{0} & \color{#f00}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \color{#f00}{1} & \color{#f00}{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{#0b5}{0} & \color{#0b5}{1} & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{#0b5}{1} & \color{#0b5}{0} & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{#07c}{0} & \color{#07c}{1} \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{#07c}{1} & \color{#07c}{0} \\
 \end{pmatrix} \\
 \hline
 \text{NOR} &
 \begin{array}{}
  \left|000\right> \mapsto \color{#f00}{\left|001\right>} \\
  \color{#999}{\left|001\right> \color{#f99}{\mapsto \left|000\right>}} \\
  \left|010\right> \mapsto \left|010\right> \\
  \color{#999}{\left|011\right> \mapsto \left|011\right>} \\
  \left|100\right> \mapsto \left|100\right> \\
  \color{#999}{\left|101\right> \mapsto \left|101\right>} \\
  \left|110\right> \mapsto \left|110\right> \\
  \color{#999}{\left|111\right> \mapsto \left|111\right>} \\
 \end{array} &
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \color{#f00}{0} & \color{#f00}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \color{#f00}{1} & \color{#f00}{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{pmatrix} \\
 \hline
 \text{XOR} &
 \begin{array}{}
  \left|00\right> \mapsto \left|00\right> \\
  \left|01\right> \mapsto \left|01\right> \\
  \left|10\right> \mapsto \color{#f00}{\left|11\right>} \\
  \left|11\right> \mapsto \color{#f00}{\left|10\right>} \\
 \end{array} &
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & \color{#f00}{0} & \color{#f00}{1} \\
  0 & 0 & \color{#f00}{1} & \color{#f00}{0} \\
 \end{pmatrix} \\
 \hline
 \text{XNOR} &
 \begin{array}{}
  \left|00\right> \mapsto \color{#f00}{\left|01\right>} \\
  \left|01\right> \mapsto \color{#f00}{\left|00\right>} \\
  \left|10\right> \mapsto \left|10\right> \\
  \left|11\right> \mapsto \left|11\right> \\
 \end{array} &
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \color{#f00}{0} & \color{#f00}{1} & 0 & 0 \\
  \color{#f00}{1} & \color{#f00}{0} & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 \end{pmatrix} \\
 \hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 3):

## Simulating "Classical AND Gate" using "Toffoli Gate" (also known as "Controlled-Controlled-NOT Gate", or "CCNOT Gate")

With the help of [Blue](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/26/blue)'s comment, and the Wikipedia pages [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate#Toffoli_(CCNOT)_gate) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate#Universality_and_Toffoli_gate), a solution to simulating classical AND gate was found.

The CCNOT gate is a 3-qubit gate having the following properties:

- If both the 1st and 2nd inputs are $\left|1\right>$, then it flips the 3rd input while keeping the 1st and 2nd inputs unchanged;
- Otherwise, it keeps all inputs unchanged.

The net effect of this gate is:

- It keeps the 1st qubit unchanged;
- It keeps the 2nd qubit unchanged;
- It outputs "the 3rd qubit XOR (the 1st qubit AND the 2nd qubit)" as the result of the 3rd qubit.

In table form, the function looks like:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & \color{red}{1}\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & \color{red}{0}\end{array} \\
 \hline  
\end{array}
$$

In matrix form, it looks like:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

If we want to calculate $\left|x\right>$ AND $\left|y\right>$, we can:

- Prepare the 1st input to be $\left|x\right>$;
- Prepare the 2nd input to be $\left|y\right>$;
- Prepare the 3rd input to be $\left|0\right>$.

Since we prepare the 3rd input to be $\left|0\right>$ on purpose, we can just ignore the cases where the 3rd input is $\left|1\right>$. By removing  all the rows containing a $1$ in the 3rd input (i.e. the 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th row) from the table above, it becomes:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & \color{red}{1}\end{array} \\
 \hline  
\end{array}
$$

The net effect of the gate in this setting is:

- It keeps the 1st qubit unchanged;
- It keeps the 2nd qubit unchanged;
- It outputs "<s>the 3rd qubit XOR</s> (the 1st qubit AND the 2nd qubit)" as the result of the 3rd qubit, since "0 XOR x = x" for any "x".

If we just look at the 1st input, the 2nd input, and the 3rd output, the table is exactly the same as the classical AND gate:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\end{array} & 0 \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\end{array} & 0 \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\end{array} & 0 \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\end{array} & \color{red}{1} \\
 \hline  
\end{array}
$$

Comment: @Blue Thanks! I am improving my wordings and thinking about the solution for OR right now.

Answer (score 1):

## Simulating "Classical OR Gate"

Please read [my answer for simulating "Classical AND Gate"](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5832/6152) in this post first.

In this answer, I am going to use another approach to reach the solution. Let's begin with the table for classical OR gate:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 0\end{array} & 0 \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}0 & 1\end{array} & 1 \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\end{array} & 1 \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\end{array} & 1 \\
 \hline  
\end{array}
$$

As discussed in the comment section of the question, it is impossible for any 2-qubit quantum gate to simulate a classical OR gate - an [ancilla bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancilla_bit) is needed to do so.

Let's see the table for the 3-qubit identity gate:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline  
\end{array}
$$

Let's assume the solution to be similar to that of classical AND gate - if we want to calculate $\left|x\right>$ OR $\left|y\right>$, we can:

- Prepare the 1st input to be $\left|x\right>$;
- Prepare the 2nd input to be $\left|y\right>$;
- $\color{red}{\text{Prepare the 3rd input to be some value}}$.

Let's separate the table above by rows having $\left|0\right>$ as the 3rd input, and rows having $\left|1\right>$ as the 3rd input:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline  
\end{array} \\
\end{array}
$$

It is trivial to see that the table on the right looks more similar to the classical OR gate, and thus is a better starting point. Therefore, we choose to  $\color{red}{\text{prepare the 3rd input to be} \left|1\right>}$.

Since it is not possible to modify just one entry in the table to make a valid quantum gate - the resulting matrix will not be a unitary matrix, we need to pair it up and swap the values with another entry:

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & \color{red}{1}\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & \color{red}{0}\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline  
\end{array} \\
\end{array}
$$

Merging them back into one table, we get:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
 \hline
 \text{Input} & \text{Output} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & \color{red}{1}\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 0 & \color{red}{0}\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 0 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 0\end{array} \\
 \hline  
 \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\end{array} & \begin{array}{ccc}1 & 1 & 1\end{array} \\
 \hline  
\end{array}
$$

Then it is trivial to see the matrix is:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

It is easy to show that the matrix above is unitary.

P.S.: I don't know if there is a name for this quantum gate, or how it could be written in terms of other named gates.