# Transferring classical OR gate in a quantum gate

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis

I would be interested to know how to transform the classic OR gate into a quantum gate. I thought a little about myself. The OR gate can also be rewritten as a NAND gate:

[image]

So, I have now tried to convert into a quantum circuit. If the lower bit of the Toffoli gate is 0, then the AND operation is performed. Accordingly, I have introduced the NOT gate to replace the NANDs.

[image]

My question, is that right? Or how would the OR gate look like a quantum gate?

Comment: **Related**: [Implementing "Classical AND Gate" and "Classical OR Gate" with a quantum circuit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/5838)

Comment: This is de Morgan’s rule. You probably strictly don’t need to invert A and B after Toffoli but it looks correct for the bottom qubit.