# Converting a Matrix to a Gate in OpenQasm 2

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, ibm-q-experience, density-matrix, gate-synthesis

I am a beginner when it comes to quantum computing so forgive me if this is a dumb question. Does anyone know how to create a gate from any matrix on OpenQasm2? Specifically, can anyone provide any tips on how to convert a matrix to Qubit rotations using the U gate in OpenQasm2? Also, could you form an addition gate using a similarly designed matrix in [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5829/implementing-classical-and-gate-and-classical-or-gate-with-a-quantum-circuit)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one example of a way to do it programmatically:

```
from cirq import Circuit, LineQubit, ops

from qbraid.interface import random_unitary_matrix
from qbraid.transpiler.cirq_qasm import to_qasm

n_qubits = 1
matrix = random_unitary_matrix(dim=2**n_qubits)

qubits = [LineQubit(i) for i in range(n_qubits)]
circuit = Circuit(ops.MatrixGate(matrix)(*qubits))

qasm_str = to_qasm(circuit)

print(circuit)
print(qasm_str)
```

```
      ┌                           ┐
0: ───│-0.255-0.574j  0.266-0.731j│───
      │-0.644-0.436j  0.131+0.615j│
      └                           ┘

// Generated from qBraid v0.4.0

OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";


// Qubits: [q(0)]
qreg q[1];


u3(pi*1.4327602146,pi*0.822476743,pi*0.2440365932) q[0];
```

Can then track the [qbraid.transpiler.cirq_qasm.to_qasm](https://github.com/qBraid/qBraid/blob/5143b038b96e46787c019be30504db86042c4cbe/qbraid/transpiler/cirq_qasm/qasm_conversions.py#L54) source code back through [cirq.QasmOutput](https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/blob/16ed00d39d186f4d5c822747a60ceac79d630a28/cirq-core/cirq/circuits/qasm_output.py#L157) and break down the procedure step-by-step.